# Change URL of masked domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-masking

Hi I have a domain that is mask forwarded to a free hosting with their given domain. How do I change all my pages urls so that it doesn't show the free hosting site information.

For example. A person types www.mydomain.com

Once the domain gets forwarded they see the free hosting site subdomain something like this: www.subdomain.freesite.com/aboutus.html

I want the user and search engines to see www.mydomain.com/aboutus.html

What is the code I need to achieve this.